Request permission storage in old and new api flutter
I need to dowload file from internet and save it into Dowload folder of user Device. But my code is not running well. I think it due to sdkInt version I pass ? How to fix this ?
here is my .xml file
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

and here the function I call to ask for request and dowload file :
              onPressed: () async {
                bool storage = true;
                bool videos = true;
                bool photos = true;
                bool manage = true;
                DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
                AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
                if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt >= 30) {
                  videos = await Permission.videos.status.isGranted;
                  photos = await Permission.photos.status.isGranted;
                  manage = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.isGranted;
                } else {
                  storage = await Permission.storage.status.isGranted;
                }
                // final baseStorage = await getDownloadsDirectory();

                if (storage && videos && photos && manage) {
                  await deleteFile(File(
                      "/storage/emulated/0/Download/app${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)}.apk"));
                  final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                    url:
                        'MyUrl.apk',
                    headers: {}, // optional: header send with url (auth token etc)
                    savedDir: '/storage/emulated/0/Download',
                    saveInPublicStorage: true,
                    fileName:
                        'app${DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10)}.apk',
                    showNotification:
                        true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                    openFileFromNotification:
                        true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
                  );
                } else {
                  if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt >= 30) {
                    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
                    await Permission.requestInstallPackages.request();
                  } else {
                    await Permission.storage.request();
                    await Permission.requestInstallPackages.request();
                  }
                }
              },

